# Pandas - How to group sub columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I create the following dataframe:

```
          Date  ProductID  SubProductId  Value
0   2015-01-02          1             1     11
1   2015-01-02          1             2     12
2   2015-01-02          1             3     NaN
3   2015-01-02          1             4     NaN
4   2015-01-02          2             1     14
5   2015-01-02          2             2     15
6   2015-01-02          2             3     16
7   2015-01-03          1             1     17
8   2015-01-03          1             2     18
9   2015-01-03          1             3     NaN
10  2015-01-03          1             4     21
11  2015-01-03          2             1     20
12  2015-01-03          2             2     21
```

And then I group the subproducts by products:

```
 df.set_index(['Date','ProductID','SubProductId']).unstack(['ProductID','SubProductId'])
```

and I would like to get the following:

```
             Value
ProductID        1                        2
SubProductId     1     2     3     4      1     2     3
Date
2015-01-02    11.0  12.0    NaN   NaN    14.0  15.0  16.0
2015-01-03    17.0  18.0    NaN   21.0   20.0  21.0   NaN
```

But what it does when I print it is that it pulls every column that start with some NaN at the end:

```
                 Value
    ProductID        1           2                  1
    SubProductId     1     2     1     2     3      4      3
    Date
    2015-01-02    11.0  12.0     14.0  15.0  16.0   NaN   NaN
    2015-01-03    17.0  18.0     20.0  21.0   NaN   21.0  NaN
```

How to have every sub columns grouped under its corresponding column ? even the sub columns that contain NaN

NB: Versions used:

- Python version: 3.6.0
- Pandas version: 0.19.2

Comment: so question is how get NaN columns as end columns?

Comment: Code as posted produces the result you say you want. What version of pandas, python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have ordered column names, you can use `sort_level` with `axis = 1` to sort the column index:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Date','ProductID','SubProductId']).unstack(['ProductID','SubProductId'])

# sort in descending order
df1.sortlevel(axis=1, ascending=False)

#             Value                                  
#ProductID        2                 1                
#SubProductId     3     2     1     4   3     2     1
#Date                                                
#2015-01-02    16.0  15.0  14.0   NaN NaN  12.0  11.0
#2015-01-03     NaN  21.0  20.0  21.0 NaN  18.0  17.0

# sort in ascending order
df1.sortlevel(axis=1, ascending=True)

#             Value                                  
#ProductID        1                     2            
#SubProductId     1     2   3     4     1     2     3
#Date                                                
#2015-01-02    11.0  12.0 NaN   NaN  14.0  15.0  16.0
#2015-01-03    17.0  18.0 NaN  21.0  20.0  21.0   NaN
```